# Why can't I change the values ​in one pandas column only?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my data frame where I have emails and not emails.

with this slice I can only get the fields that are without email:

```
df[~df['email'].str.contains('@', case=False)]['email']
```

But when I try to replace it with a value of my preference:

```
df[~df['email'].str.contains('@', case=False)]['email'] = 'No'
```

The column does not receive the change.

I don't get any error, just the following warning:

```
/home/rockstar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

follows an image of my complete dataframe:

[image: python]

Also, `df[~df['email'].str.contains('@',case=False)] = 'No'` works perfectly but I end up losing data from the rest of the line

Comment: Use `df.loc[~df['email'].str.contains('@', case=False), 'email'] = 'No'` You're using chained assignment, so you don't change the underlying data. Use `loc` like with the above to properly select both row and columns at the same time and set the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following example code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"E-mail":["abc@de", "abcde"]})
df['E-mail'].loc[~df['E-mail'].str.contains('@', case = False)] = 'No'
```